# How to use Button class In Selenium Webdriver by the help of Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code:

```
<div class="meal_buton_cont">
<button class="pink_button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Add Selected to Shopping List</button>
<button id="add_meal" class="gray_button">+ Add Meal</button>
</div>
```

I am using this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("pink_button")).click();
```

But no popup open but some time open but not item take, it show blank.

How to create script for clicking `Pink_button` then my popup will be open?

Please help me

Comment: Add some more details to the question like html content of your page.
Whether the popup appears when clicking the pink button manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Few things to consider..Wait before the element appears using explicit waits like `WebDriverWait` API. Once the element is clickable using `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeclickable(WebElement)` then click on it and again wait till the pop-up appears. if its alert then use `ExpectedConditions.alsertIsPresent()` with `WebDriverWait`